# How can I create my own GO slim?

Tags: gene, gene-ontology, ontology

I know there are existing GO slims predefined. But does anyone know how I can create my own collection of GO terms for enrichment analysis?

Comment: I have never created one, but a GO slims is just a list of GO associated with genes, so you just need to download the list of GO and associate them with your list of genes.  What have you tried/searched? What do you need that it is not covered in the [FAQ](http://www.geneontology.org/faq/how-do-i-create-user-defined-go-slim)?

Comment: GO slims are just a subset of the gene ontology graph. Just a group of terms, no genes. We can't help you create one if you don't explain what terms you want and what sort of analysis you want to do.

Comment: I have a list of genes enriched in kidney. So I want to get a list of kidney-related terms and see which of them are significantly enriched.

Comment: @Dr_Hope Then what you really want is to test an enrichment in GO related to kidney  not create a GO slim. But if you only use a subset of genes and a subset of GOs the test would be biased (AFAIk) if you don't tell the suitable background population of genes and GO terms.

Comment: I've already done a canonical GO to check the background. The enriched terms are mostly kidney-related because our sample is a kidney. That's why I need a GO slim to check kidney-only terms.